# Why does my Cricut cut some images in the right place, and some off to the left?

Tags: tool-usage

I'm trying to do print and cut stickers and some don't work out.

I've attached two examples — the one with the flag always comes out perfect, but the illustrations with the white outlines always come out offset, even if I try to cut them without the white border and with bleed on.

(The third image is a literal photo of Cricut Design Space, showing the illustrations have an even white border.)

Because some come out perfect and some don't, I'm comfortable saying it's not a lighting or calibration issue. (Also, I have adjusted the lighting and recalibrated multiple times.)

Any help?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I have no experience with CriCut, but it looks like the 0-coordinate / reference point in one of your files is off. Which software do you use? Is there a special software for CriCut?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  Almost every question on the site gets at least one answer if there's an answer to be had.  If Elmy's suggestion doesn't turn out to be the issue, the lack of answers suggests that the site doesn't have a big pool of CriCut users.  If you still need a solution, you might want to try a site where CriCut users congregate (the company may even have a dedicated support forum).  If you do manage to solve this, please post an answer.  Good luck.

Comment: There are a (very!) few CriCut questions over on Graphic Design, so I am going to migrate this in the hopes you'll get an answer.

Comment: @Erica Please dont do that... just because theres a tag and answer does not mean its ontopic. THis is a production issue, ina corner of design that is not even tradittionaly thought of being graphic design

Comment: @joojaa I was going off of what looks like registration errors during transfer from electronic media to printed, not the tag; sorry it is not something that Graphic Design would be able to help with.

Comment: @Erica its a machine calibration issue.  Graohic design is about drawing the item. Uts drawn correctly

Comment: it's definitely a machine issue, not a design issue. Cricut support has basically told me there's not much to be done about it — sometimes the registration detection just doesn't work.